# How to keep a variable A unaltered when operations are done on a second variable B only, whose value was assigned as equal to A in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

Suppose we have two variables A and b(containing non-dictionary type element) and initially i make A=B.Now,i do operations on A and A only,and eventually value of A changes.The value of B should not change since,I want B to be the same value as it was initially that is equal to the previous value of A.But as A changes B changes too.How to store the initial value of A at variable B so that it does not change?

e.g.-

```
A=B
<operations on A> only
print B
```

This gives the value of A after operation.I want to modify this such that,when printed B gives the initial value of A,not the changed value.

Comment: Please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: using [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: if you have integer/float or string in variable then it can't change. If you have list or dictionary then make copy `A = B.copy()`. For other objects you may need `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()`. For more complex list/dictionary you may also need `A = copy.deepcopy(B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value of B should not change since,I want B to be the same value as it was initially that is equal to the previous value of A.

This is not true. Using the equal sign `=` means that the variable name will be pointing to an object on the right-hand side.

For example:

```py
a = list(1, 2)
b = a
```

means that **both** `a` **and** `b` point to the object `list(1, 2)`.
Therefore, changing `a` changes `b`.

As suggested in the comments, this is solved by using `copy`/`deepcopy` and in case of immutable data types this problem does not occur. Consider this:

```py
a = 1
b = a # points to the same object as `a`

b = a + 1
```

Here in the last line a new object is created since `int`s are immutable and there is no way of changing the object `1`.
Similarly with strings.

Hope this helps.